# golang http handler context

Tags: go, boltdb

I'm trying to understand variable scopes in golang with the following code.
In this example, calling in http a page will echo the uri query combined with a stored value in Boltdb.

The problem is that the database driver doesn't seem to run correctly in the http handler context: it doesn't print anything to stdout nor to the http request.

I was expecting it to print :

> He's loving <'uri query content'> but prefers pizza (data from bolt.db driver)

How to fix this code?
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "github.com/boltdb/bolt"
)

var db bolt.DB

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dberr := db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
    log.Println("here")
        b := tx.Bucket([]byte("MyBucket"))
            loving := b.Get([]byte("loving"))
        log.Printf("He's loving %s but prefers %s",r.URL.Path[1:], string(loving))
            fmt.Fprintf(w,"He's loving %s but prefers %s",r.URL.Path[1:], string(loving) )
        return nil
    })
    if dberr != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("db update: %s", dberr)
    }
    log.Printf("Finished handling")
}

func main() {

    db, err := bolt.Open("my.db", 0600, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }else{
        log.Println("database opened")
    }
    dberr := db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        b, err := tx.CreateBucketIfNotExists([]byte("MyBucket"))
        if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("create bucket: %s", err)
        }
        err2 := b.Put([]byte("loving"), []byte("pizza"))
        if err2 != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("put loving: %s", err2)
        }
        loving := b.Get([]byte("loving"))
        log.Printf("He's loving %s", string(loving))
        return nil
    })

        if dberr != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("db update: %s", err)
        }
    defer db.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see your bug. This one is usually a little difficult to track because its just the `:` in front of the equals. It was basically a scoping issue because you declared `db` as a global while at the same time creating a `db` variable that was scoped to your main function.

You used `db, err := ...` to assign the values instead of just `=`. `:=` will both declare and infer the type. Since its also doing declaration, the `db` you're using in the `main` function is not the `db` you have declared in the global scope. Meanwhile the handler is still attempting to use the `db` that was declared in the global scope. The below code is the same code as you initially had with a few comments in the code to outline what the working changes are. Hope this helps!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/boltdb/bolt"
)

var db *bolt.DB // this is going to be a pointer and is going to be nil until its set by the main function

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dberr := db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        log.Println("here")
        b := tx.Bucket([]byte("MyBucket"))
        loving := b.Get([]byte("loving"))
        log.Printf("He's loving %s but prefers %s", r.URL.Path[1:], string(loving))
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "He's loving %s but prefers %s", r.URL.Path[1:], string(loving))
        return nil
    })
    if dberr != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("db update: %s", dberr)
    }
    log.Printf("Finished handling")
}

func main() {
    var err error                           // this will have to be declared because of the next line to assign db the first value returned from `bolt.Open`
    db, err = bolt.Open("my.db", 0600, nil) // notice that this has changed and is no longer `db, err := ...` rather its `db, err = ...`
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("database opened")
    }
    dberr := db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        b, err := tx.CreateBucketIfNotExists([]byte("MyBucket"))
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("create bucket: %s", err)
        }
        err2 := b.Put([]byte("loving"), []byte("pizza"))
        if err2 != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("put loving: %s", err2)
        }
        loving := b.Get([]byte("loving"))
        log.Printf("He's loving %s", string(loving))
        return nil
    })

    if dberr != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("db update: %s", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```